# mysql get records greater than 10 hours

Tags: mysql

I have a time stamp in my table(2012-04-04 20:44:53) and i would like to select all of the records that are greater than 10.5 hours from the current time. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE yourtimestampfield <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 10.5 HOUR)
```